# Gitlab Runner: return code of "mvn verify" changes when redirecting output

Tags: windows, maven, cmd, gitlab-ci

Note: I am using a windows build node with powershell.
Previously, I was executing the following in a gitlab CI job:

```
- mvn --version
- mvn verify -fae
- mvn -D"tycho.mode"=maven jacoco:report -D"jacoco.dataFile"="../target/jacoco.exec" sonar:sonar
```

Now, I am redirecting the output of `mvn verify -fae` to a file:

```
- mvn verify -fae > testOutput.txt 2>&1
```

The build output is written to the desired file, but apparently, the exit code is "1", even though the tests complete successfully.

If I do not redirect stderr to file, i.e. leave away `2>$1`, everything works okay. Another strange thing: if I wrap the command in a powershell script, the $ERRORLEVEL variable is 0, so the exit code should be 0.

Does anybody know what could be going on?

Comment: Does `call mvn …` change anything? (is `mvn` actually called `mvn.bat` or `mvn.cmd`?)

Comment: @aschipfl I cannot use "call" because the build appears to be in a powershell. `mvn` links to `mvn.cmd`. Even more strange: I wrapped the call in a power shell script, and there the `$ERRORLEVEL` variable is 0, so success. The faulty behavior also only occurs if I redirect stderr to the file.

Answer (score 1):

At first you have to make shell to redirect File Decriptors (FD) and only then you should define a file.

`- mvn verify -fae > 2>&1 > testOutput.txt`

If you need to redirect your output to file and also see it in your session so you may use 'tee':

`- mvn verify -fae 2>&1 | tee testOutput.txt`

Comment: Please consider that I am using a windows build node. I think that the syntax for the redirection should be correct there?

Comment: I haven't noticed that you use windows in your message. Your syntax is ok. I have no idea why you could get exitcode 1.